# Mongoose - `unique` are not updated after delete

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm currently using `mongoose` and `mongoose-unique-validator` to enforce `unique` index to a certain field to avoid duplicate values. I already know about how `unique` works in `mongoose`, so I decided to use `mongoose-unique-validator` for ease of development

However, after I deleted a document and inserted a new one with the same value on the `unique` field, my query gets rejected with duplication error.

Here's the schema in question

```js
export const categorySchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    trim: true,
    required: true,
    index: true,
    maxlength: 25,
  },

  desc: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: true,
    maxlength: 100,
  },
}, {
  versionKey: false,
});

categorySchema.plugin(uniqueValidator);

export const Category = model<CategoryDocument>(
  'Category',
  categorySchema,
);
```

As far as I know, mongoDB always updated the index after `update` and `delete`. So, I didn't expect this outcome.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

EDIT: Here's the error log

```
MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error dup key: { : "Category 1" }
      at Function.create (node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\error.js:44:12)
      at toError (node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:150:22)
      at coll.s.topology.insert (node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\common_functions.js:265:39)
      at handler (node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\sdam\topology.js:971:24)
      at wireProtocol.(anonymous function) (node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\sdam\server.js:496:5)
      at C:\Users\Namchee\Desktop\brita\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\pool.js:420:18
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
```

EDIT2: The actual test script (dependencies is omitted)

```
const expect = chai.expect;

before(async () => {
  const mongod = new MongoMemoryServer();

  mongoose.Promise = Promise;

  const uri = await mongod.getConnectionString();

  const mongooseOpts = {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
  };

  await mongoose.connect(uri, mongooseOpts);

// clear it before test
  await Promise.all([
    Announcement.deleteMany({}),
    Category.deleteMany({}),
  ]);
});

after(async () => {
// clear it after testing
  await Promise.all([
    Announcement.deleteMany({}),
    Category.deleteMany({}),
  ]);

  mongoose.disconnect();
});

describe('Announcement repository test', () => {
  let category1;
  let category2;
  let announcement1;
  let announcement2;

  const announcementRepository = new AnnouncementRepositoryMongo(
    Announcement,
  );

  before(async () => {
    const categoryFetch = await Category.find();

    console.log(categoryFetch); // empty

    const category = await Category.create(
      {
        name: 'Category 1',
        desc: 'This is category 1',
      },
      {
        name: 'Category 2',
        desc: 'This is category 2',
      },
    ); // error when trying to execute this

    category1 = category[0];
    category2 = category[1];

    const announcements = await Announcement.create(
      {
        title: faker.random.word(),
        content: faker.random.words(10),
        validUntil: faker.date.recent(),
        important: false,
        categories: [category1, category2],
      },
      {
        title: faker.random.word(),
        content: faker.random.words(15),
        validUntil: faker.date.recent(),
        important: true,
        categories: [category1],
      },
    );

    announcement1 = announcements[0];
    announcement2 = announcements[1];
  });

  describe('findAll', () => {
    it('should return all announcements', async () => {
      const spy = sinon.spy(Announcement, 'find');

      const announcements = await announcementRepository.findAll();

      spy.restore();

      expect(spy.calledOnce).to.be.true;
      expect(announcements.length).to.equal(2);

      expect(announcements[0].id.toString())
        .to.equal(announcement1.id.toString());

      expect(announcements[1].id.toString())
        .to.equal(announcement2.id.toString());
    });
  });
```

Comment: Can you please paste the duplication error here?

Comment: I think you still have a category with name **Category 1** in categorySchema collection, that's it says so

Comment: When you run your code for the first time, it creates a category, deletes it, and creates it again. So far so good. When you run second time, you get the unique validation exception (because it was created in the first run.) Actually it is the first create operation which causes error, not the one you commented.

Comment: @SuleymanSah Thank you for your response, but actually this happens on a test and I inserted the data on global `before` and always cleared it in global `after` hook. I can even verify that when fetching the data on scoped `before`, the category array is empty. Added the actual script.